# For loop overflow vector size

Tags: c++, loops, vector, overflow, break

I have two vectors - one is global and second one local. I need to copy elements from local vector to global in order 1st, 4th, 7th, ... In the local one is array of size 6. My code works fine but it always make one more iteration which leads to loading wrong data. On the last iteration it also copy wrong data. Do you have any idea what is wrong in my code?

```
int iter = 0;
float nr;

for (i = 0; i < vect_local.size(); i++){
    iter += 1;
    nr = vect_local[i];
    vect_global.push_back(nr);
    i += 2;

    if((vect_local.size()/iter) == 3){
        iter = 0;
        break;
    }
}
```

EDIT: for (i = 0; i < **=** vect_local.size(); i++)
Stupid typo. But my problem is still the same...

Comment: @astrak What does this condition if((vect_local.size()/iter) == 3){
 mean?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: When I have executed my code I always overflowed vector. So I tried to stop it by break statement. When I changed iteration in for cycle acording to tomer.z it works. I don't know what difference is between these two codes...

Answer (score 1):

your loop condition should be i < vect_local.size() because the last index is size-1

```
int iter = 0;
float nr;

for (i = 0; i < vect_local.size(); i+=3){
//            ^
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. When I print i befor if clause I got last i equal to 5 which is not correct.

Comment: @astrak Vector starts counting at zero, not one so: { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} <= that's 6 values. (count them)

Comment: Edited my comment so you wont need that i+=2 inside the for, it isnt really proper coding to advance the i in a for loop.
Just so you know :)

Comment: When I corrected iteration to i+=3 it works! Why it didn't work in my example?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Something like this ?

```
int main () {

int globalarray[16]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};
int localarray[6]={0,0,0,0,0,0};   
int internalcounter=0;

for(int i=0;i<int(sizeof(globalarray)/sizeof(int));i=i+3)
{
 localarray[internalcounter] = globalarray[i];
 internalcounter+=1;
}

for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
 cout<<localarray[i]<<endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

That prints :
1
4
7
10
13
16

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it is more difficult when you have vectors. There is not possible to use "=" for assigning one vector value to another vector (maybe if you overload this operator).